# Permissions error when retrieving uploaded file

Tags: php, iis, file-upload, iis-7, file-permissions

I'm running php on IIS 7 on my localhost for testing purposes. A user can upload a resume as part of a job application. The php receives the file and uploads it to the uploads directory.

Later, an employer can login to a company web portal and view all the current applications. They are able to click on View resume to download a copy of the resume. I have set the uploads folder to grant full permissions to both IUSR and IIS_IUSR.

For the existing resumes in this folder, the permissions are correctly passed on and the employer is able to download a copy of these files. However when a new file is uploaded, the permissions are not passed to this file and the employer is met with an error when trying to download it.

With this code I am able to download the resumes that existed before I changed the permissions of the folder, however I am met with a

**HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server.**

when I try to download newly uploaded files.

**Upload code:**

```
    $name = sprintf('uploads/%s.%s',
        sha1_file($_FILES['file-0']['tmp_name']),
        $ext
    );
    if (!move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['file-0']['tmp_name'], $name
    )) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Failed to move uploaded file.');
    }
```

**Download code**

```
echo "<h3><a href='" . $resume . "' class='linkText'>Link to resume</a></h3>";
```

How do I modify my setup to pass on the permissions to newly uploaded files?

Comment: have you bothered looking at the permissions on the "new" files v.s the permissions on the "old" files?

Comment: The permissions on the new files for IUSR and IIS_USR are both blank. However the old files have full access for both of these users. The directory also has full access for both of these users. I just don't know how to pass the directories acl to the new files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just changed how I outputted the download link. Rather than making it a direct link to the file I used `readfile`

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: ' . $array['filetype']);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($resume));
readfile($resume);
```

For some reason this works fine and there are no errors about permissions.